# Chromium didn't shut down correctly and Google account always logged out

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, chromium

I use RPI 3 model B and I reinstall Raspberry Pi OS for some reason. I could log in to Google and it kept logged in whenever I close and open Chromium, but it was before I reinstall raspios. However, now, after doing a fresh install (Release date: May 7th 2021), after logging in to Google account, and then closing Chromium, and then open it again, there's a message "Chromium didn't shut down correctly" and the Google account is logged out, I need to log in every time launching Chromium. Please help me to solve the issue.

What I've tried:

1. Searching for the solution on the internet: no solution found, almost all problems related to kiosk mode but I don't use kiosk mode
2. Deleting chromium config to get all the default and fresh configs
3. Testing login in another site: my login to this site persists, seems happens only to Google (including Youtube)
4. Using Firefox: it works, the login persists, but unfortunately there's another issue: some Youtube videos' sound doesn't work
5. Making sure that the system is up to date (`apt update && apt upgrade`)

**UPDATE**

6. Reinstalling chromium-browser
7. Disabling the 2 default extensions

Output of stdout/stderr:

```
## launch

libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
[...:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(150)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[...:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(621)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get: object_path= /org/freedesktop/UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files
[...:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(621)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.UPower.GetDisplayDevice: object_path= /org/freedesktop/UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files
[...:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(621)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.UPower.EnumerateDevices: object_path= /org/freedesktop/UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files

## log in to google and then quit

[...:ERROR:event_router.cc(714)] Event dispatched while shutting down extensions browser client.
[...:ERROR:event_router.cc(714)] Event dispatched while shutting down extensions browser client.
Trace/breakpoint trap

## launch again

libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
[...:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(150)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[...:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(621)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get: object_path= /org/freedesktop/UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files
[...:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(621)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.UPower.GetDisplayDevice: object_path= /org/freedesktop/UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files
[...:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(621)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.UPower.EnumerateDevices: object_path= /org/freedesktop/UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files


## quit again (no output)
```

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall it ? And what loggs have you checked ?

Comment: I've just tried to `apt reinstall chromium-browser` and it's still not solved. Did you mean what it writes to stdout while quitting chromium? It is `event_router.cc(714)] Event dispatched while shutting down extensions browser client.`

Comment: not just std out but log files that can give a hint.

Comment: And perhaps this can shed some light https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=257747

Comment: @MatsK which log files did you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I can solve it, seems the problem is with Chromium sign-in or Google authentication itself. After disabling Chromium sign-in, the session/login persists after closing and then reopening Chromium.

1. In Chromium, open **Settings**.
2. Click **Sync and Google services**.
3. Uncheck **Allow Chromium sign-in**.
4. Log in to Google like usual.